# Import custom JS in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using the latest `create-ract-app`version for my project and I have a `custom.js` file with a `CustomFunction` function in it.
I need is to access to the `CustomFunction`function from one of my components.

Which is the best way to achieve this?
Importing the file into `index.html` like below, I have `'CustomFunction' is not defined  no-undef'` error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <!-- jQuery import -->
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom Style and JS import -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CustomComponent/custom.css">
    <script src="./CustomComponent/custom.js"></script>
```

This is the project structure:

```
10 ├── public
 11 │   ├── customComponent
 12 │   │   ├── custom.js
 13 │   │   └── custom.css
 14 │   ├── favicon.ico
 15 │   ├── index.html
 16 │   └── manifest.json
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is export the function form you custom.js file like

```
const CustomFunction = () => {

}

export {CustomFunction};
```

Now you can import it in any of the component like

```
import {CustomFunction} from './path/to/custom.js';
```

If you have multiple of them in component.js, which you want to use in other components then you can export them like

```
export {
    CustomFunction,
    CustomVariable,
    CustomVar2,
    CustomFunction2
}
```

And import like

```
import {CustomFunction, CustomVariable, CustomVar2, CustomFunction2} from './path/to/custom.js';
```

Comment: Do I need to export each single variable and function form my Custom file? There are a lot of those... Is it the right way to go?

Comment: Please don't mix CommonJS syntax (module.exports) with ES6 syntax (import). Either use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Ok @DanAbramov, I will update the answer as soon as I reach home

Comment: Also no, you don't need to export *every* variable. You need to export only what you will use (the component in this case). See how `src/App.js` exports a component and `src/index.js` imports it in the newly created project. The User Guide also includes instructions on importing files: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#importing-a-component

Comment: @DanAbramov, Yes you only need to export variable that you later on will be using, I though it was evident and did not add it in the answer explicitly

Comment: @DanAbramov thanks for the edit, I dont know how that `=` got in that place ;)